# c# using DataTable AsEnumerable() on .NET 2

Tags: c#, linq, .net-2.0, datatable, asenumerable

I am trying to run the following code on a .net 2 winforms app:

```
DataTable dt = this.GetData(null, null, true, sql);

DateTime minDate = (from f in dt.AsEnumerable()
               select f.Field<DateTime>("Timestamp")).Min();
```

I am getting errors for the "using system.linq" and the ".AsEnumerable()". Is there any way I can resolve this to use AsEnumerable()? Or should I just abandon this method?

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

.NET 2 doesn't *have* LINQ. You could use [LINQBridge](http://linqbridge.googlecode.com), which may or may not include the `AsEnumerable()` extension method for `DataTable`. If it does, you can just use `Cast<DataRow>()` instead, optionally via an explicitly typed range variable:

```
DateTime minDate = (from DataRow f in dt.AsEnumerable()
                    select f.Field<DateTime>("Timestamp")).Min();
```

You'd then *also* need the `Field<T>` extension method on `DataRow`. You could probably write that yourself though, if it's not part of LINQBridge.

Just to make it clear - *none* of this will work pleasantly if you're also using Visual Studio 2005, because you need the C# 3 features of lambda expressions, extension methods etc.

Is there any possibility you could upgrade to .NET 3.5? It would make life a lot easier...

Answer (score 0):

LINQ was introduced in .NET 3.5, so I'm afraid you are out of luck here :(

Comment: yeah, I'm aware of that, thought there might be some hope though! :)

Comment: @Funky - I guess your only hope is LINQBridge as suggested by Mr. Skeet.